# SQL to filter multiple records based on a column

Tags: sql

I have a table which contains records a follows:

```
Column_1  Column_2  Column_3

CA        123       EN

CA        123       SP

CA        789       EN
```

My output should be as follows:

```
Column_1  Column_2  Column_3

CA         123       SP

CA         789       EN
```

I know this sql is not complicated to write, but I have tried for couple of hours already and still not got a satisfactory result. Any suggestions?

Comment: What are the queries you tried?

Comment: ...and why do you want those two rows, as opposed to any other two? Also, what server software are you using?

Comment: Thanks guys...never mind about this..i used qualify and got the result..

Comment: thanks again to all who commented and answered...

Answer (score 1):

A query that gives you that result would be:

```
select Column_1, Column_2, Column_3
from TheTable
where
  (Column_2 = 123 and Column_3 = 'SP')
  or
  (Column_2 = 789 and Column_3 = 'EN')
```

Answer (score -1):

I thought you were looking for a `group by`.

```
select Column_1, Column_2, Column_3 from table_name group by Column_2, Column_3
```

The above query works in MySQL but not in many other SQL implementations as pointed out in the comments, and I don't think it does what you actually want. Returns 3 rows, not 2.

Again, just guessing, but as I understand, maybe this is what you are looking for:

```
select Column_1, Column_2, 
  (select Column_3 from test_table t2 
   where t2.Column_1=t1.Column_1 and t2.Column_2=t1.Column_2 
   order by Column_0 desc limit 1) as Column_3
from test_table t1
group by Column_1, Column_2
```

This works in MySQL, didn't test in any other. Returns exactly the 2 rows as requested.

You can see an extra Column_0 there - that should be a primary [integer] key in your table. I presumed you have it already. If not, you need to add it, otherwise you wouldn't know which is the last row inserted in your table in order to return it when you have duplicates for Column_2.

Also, `limit 1` is specific to MySQL. The equivalent in MSSQL is `select top 1 ...`, for Firebird `select first 1 ...`, etc. You didn't specify th rdbms you are using.

Comment: Your query would not even run, on some SQL implementations (non aggregated column in an aggregated query)

Comment: That will give you a result with three rows, for databases that accepts the query. MS SQL Server for example doesn't.

Comment: Yes, you are right, and it doesn't do what he needs, as still 3 records would be shown. Reading more carefully now, I don't understand what he actually wants to achieve.

Comment: From what I understand: If in column 2 there's more than one the same value: show last entry of column 3... But I'm not sure that's possible in SQL...